# Select SDKs : Please provide the path to the Android SDK

Tags: android, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio and I'm getting the following error after opening Android Studio :-
Please provide the path to the Android SDK

I have tried "*C:\Users\Your Name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk*"
But the above doesn't work. It says invalid Android SDK Path. When I go to the above file location, I cannot locate any SDK file.

I also searched for SDK files on my system and this is what I got.

[image]

Comment: Android studio asks when you are going to install it. So you may have to reinstall the android studio and check the pass.

Comment: I have reinstalled it again. It shows the same error.

Comment: On Android Studio Setup Wizard, it says No Android SDK found.

Comment: Check this step: https://developer.android.com/studio/install check videos for all the os. You can see the SDK path in it.

Comment: The link that you sent didn't help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't open the android studio after installation. The sdk will be installed when you open the android studio. Then you can find its location in a setting tab.